# wpf catch invalid input to textbox with string format N2 on bound item

Tags: wpf, xaml

There is probably a simple answer to this but I can't seem to find it. I have a textbox on my window that is two way bound to a decimal property. I have string format = N2 to ensure valid input. Here is my xaml:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="tbxAmount"
             Text="{Binding ItemAmount, StringFormat=N2, Mode=TwoWay}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Height="23" .....
```

Validation works great - if an invalid input then the textbox is outlined in red and the property in the bound class is not changed. But...

There is a SAVE button that then saves changes made to the class properties to my database. Somehow in the SAVE button-click event I need to recognized that my textbox had invalid input and therefore prevent the database update. There must be a property indicating the format error on my textbox that i can reference, or something else I need to do to prevent the save?

Answer (score 2):

All of these answers are great. The Validation class put me on the right track for solving this the way that works best for me at the moment.

In my Save click event I currently run a verify function in my item class that returns a series of messages if there are any verification errors. Then if the messages are not blank I display the error messages instead of proceeding with the save function.

So all I needed to do was check the result of GetHasError for tbx amount and included another error message if it was true. Here is the relevent code from my Click event...
(Code in VB, save the ";"s)

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim tErrors As String = ""
    'validate
    tErrors = sInvoiceItem.InvoiceItemVerify()
    If Validation.GetHasError(tbxAmount) = True Then
        tErrors = tErrors + "The amount entered must be a valid number." + Environment.NewLine
    End If

    If tErrors = Nothing Then ' proceed with save
        ....
```

So the key for me was the Validation.GetHasError() function. Thanks to all for your input.

In future, I'd like to work more with the solutions above from ViVi and qqww2 to keep the validation within XAML, however I'm not sure how to add to this the display of a message/feedback to the user.

Likewise the response above from Robert resolves the issue of preventing invalid data from being saved, yet I wouldn't want to have the item class itself issuing messages to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The property you seek is `Validation.HasError` attached property. You can use this property to disable the button when the input is not valid.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NegateBooleanConverter x:Key="NegateBooleanConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=tbxAmount, Path=(Validation.HasError), Converter={StaticResource NegateBooleanConverter}}"/>
```

When `Validation.HasError` is `true` `IsEnabled` should be `false` and vice versa. Therefore binding should be negated. You can achieve this via a simple converter:

```
public class NegateBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool) value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

well you could probably use the Contain method to check if the text match, check this code:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox.Text.Contains(N2))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item match");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item does not match");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Another good answer, and I'll use this for windows where the data inputs are not bound to class properties.

Answer (score -2):

Rather than checking for invalid data why not prevent the data being set to an invalid value in the first place?

In the property you're binding to, use the 'set' method to check the value and format it before allowing it.

I've guessed a little at your code behind but imagine something like this would work. It's the sort of thing I use for getting numerical values from a text box and ensuring the formatting is correct.

```
private double itemAmount;
public string ItemAmount
{
    get
    {
        return itemAmount.ToString("N2");
    }
    set
    {
        double temp = 0;

        if(Double.TryParse(value, out temp))
        {
            itemAmount = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. The two way binding: "{Binding ItemAmount, StringFormat=N2, Mode=TwoWay}"  prevents the Set from being invoke if the input is not in N2 format. So the underlying field in the bound class is never updated if the value is invalid. The test you have above is redundant if the XAML includes the N2 string format. It is that validation that sets the Validation.HasError, so all of this can be accomplished before the Set is invoked. I appreciate your answer as it has given me other ideas :)

Comment: Glad it gave you ideas though why not remove the N2 from the xmal if the code behind is doing the formatting?

Comment: Because by having the XAML handle the validation, the class behind never has any chance to receive an invalid value. It's simply not invoked if the user enters an invalid character in the XAML textbox where string format is set to N2. (ps. I had given you a + vote, others must have given you the down vote).

Comment: Thanks Scott, appreciated!